# How can I de-rig & delete the skeleton while keeping the mesh?

Tags: 3dsmax, rigging

There is this 3D model one can [download here](https://www.deviantart.com/kse25/art/DBFZ-Bardock-SSJ-for-XPS-738381882) and  then import to 3DS Max with XNALara importer. (Side note: XNALara is also known as XnaPosingStudio)

Now this model already comes with a skeleton which is rigged. But if I want to rig the mesh to a different skeleton I need to delete the current skeleton correct?

When I have tried to delete the skeleton before the mesh got deleted with it.

So what I need to do is de-rig the skeleton from the mesh and then delete the skeleton, but how do I de-rig? Does anyone here know how? It's not a CAT rig.